# How can I create a Usercontrol property that interacts with the Visual Studio property window?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I'm creating a Usercontrol (Windows, not WPF) and want to add my own custom color property, as show below.  However any instances of this control show the property value of MyColor to be **System.Drawing.SolidBrush** in the property window.

```
    private Brush _MyColor = Brushes.Blue;
    [TypeConverter(typeof(System.Windows.Media.BrushConverter))]
    public Brush MyColor
    {
        get { return _MyColor; }
        set { _MyColor = value; }
    }
```

Comment: `Windows, not WPF` - WPF *is* Windows. Not to be mistaken with archaic "winforms" from 250 years ago.

Comment: I preceded my fields with the following properties, and I was able to interact with the object using the VS property window.  
[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)]
        [Browsable(true)]
        [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
        [Bindable(true)]
        public override string Text { get; set; }
        public int Radius { get; set; }
Also, perhaps there could be a need for a ToString() override in the MyColor Class that would return _MyColor?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly, you actually want to use a [UITypeEditor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171840.aspx), which allows you to have a custom editor for a property.  The TypeConverter you're using allows you to specify strings, for example, and have them automatically converted to a Brush.